# Using var with condition count statement but seems like its not working as expected in Terraform

Tags: count, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Basically the idea is when **DEPLOY_GREEN** is `true` it will execute if condition and its working properly but the issue occurs when **DEPLOY_GREEN** is `false` it's executing else condition which is expected but it also execute this `data "aws_ami" "green-capp-operations"`. Which is not supposed to happen cause i've passed `deploy_strategy=blue` with `-var`. For this reason terraform plan show me such kind of error,

```
│ Error: Invalid index

│ 

│   on data_ami.tf line 697, in output "green-example":

│  17:   value = data.aws_ami.green-example[0].id

│     ├────────────────

│     │ data.aws_ami.green-example is empty tuple
```

Why condition count statement is executing for `deploy_strategy=blue`? As per logic tt should return `0`. Did i miss anything?

Terraform Version: `v1.0.11`

For better understanding, I'm sharing code as below,

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
booleanParam(name: 'DEPLOY_GREEN', defaultValue: false, description: 'Deploy Green Infra?')

if (params.DEPLOY_GREEN) {
                        echo "DEPLOY_GREEN value: ${params.DEPLOY_GREEN}"
                        sh 'terraform plan -var deploy_strategy=green -out=myplan'

                    } else {
                        echo "DEPLOY_GREEN value: ${params.DEPLOY_GREEN}"
                        sh "terraform plan -var deploy_strategy=blue -out=myplan"
                    }
```

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "deploy_strategy" {
  type = string
}
```

**ami.tf:**

```
data "aws_ami" "green-example" {
  count = var.deploy_strategy == "green" ? 1 : 0
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${local.env}-${var.deploy_strategy}-example-*"]
    //    name = "name"
    //    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm*"]
  }
  owners      = ["self"]
  most_recent = true
}

output "green-example" {
  value = data.aws_ami.green-example[0].id
}
```

Same issue happening with ASG, TG and other resources. If i edit something with terraform code and run jenkins pipeline with **DEPLOY_GREEN** `false` its showing ASG and TG changes in `terraform plan` output when `deploy_strategy=blue`. Using same condition to create other AWS resources for green environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `green-example` output is unconditional. When the deploy strategy is not green there will be no green-example data record. So `data.aws_ami.green-example[0].id` will not be a valid expression. You must choose an appropriate value for when the deploy strategy is not green.

```
output "green-example" {
  value = data.aws_ami.green-example[0].id
}
```

In this scenario you probably want the [one](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one) function that either

- returns the first element of a 1-length list
- returns null for a 0-length list
- otherwise it raises an error

Example usage:

```
output "green-example" {
  value = one(data.aws_ami.green-example[*].id)
}
```

`*` is a type of list comprehension that expands to a list of all the ids in `green-example`. So either a 1-length list or a 0-length list in this instance. This makes it ideal for use with the `one()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've used ***one*** function in that case terraform plan is showing,

```green-example  = "ami-0fc280d8ab094a190" -> null``` and with this it will destroy green env related all resources

Comment: Yes because your saying to terraform you dont want to deploy green there for the AMI look up never happens etc. you might want to read https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-feature-toggles-blue-green-deployments-canary-test

Comment: After going through the document and implementing the method, I have encountered a confusion. Upon creating resources related to the green environment, when attempting to run Terraform plan for the blue environment, it indicates a need to destroy resources associated with the green environment.